# swiftUI tabView how to set default view onAppear?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a tabView with several views, and I would like to know how to undefine a default view when loading it.
By default, Xcode assigns the first view but I want the second view to be loaded when the application is launched.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        TabView {
            alertView()
            todayView()
            forecastView()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .onAppear
        {
            UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
            UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's move everything in explicit scene root view

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
}
```

And now we can use `selection` for this, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var selection = 2   // << here !!

  var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {   // << here !!
            alertView().tag(1)        
            todayView().tag(2)             // << here !!
            forecastView().tag(3)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .onAppear
        {
            UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
            UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one last question ! How can I put a large title like in navigation bar but without navigation interface ?

Comment: It does not relate to this topic. If you have another question, you open another topic - this is how SO works.